# Nyquist diagram of transfer function

Tags: complex-analysis, applications, control-theory

Transfer function of a system is given as $$G(s) = \frac{100(s+5)}{s^2(s+3)(s^2+4)}$$

Sketch the [Nyquist diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_plot) and find if the system is stable. Also find the gain margin and phase margin.

Please help me with this problem. Thanks.